# can't install Office 2010 via PlayonLinux Ubuntu 16.04 needs winbind but winbind is installed

Tags: playonlinux, microsoft-office

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 and am trying to install Office 2010 Home & Student via PlayonLinux.  At the beginning of the installation I get the error:
"Error in main. Please install winbind before installing Microsoft Office 2010"

However, winbind is already installed (according to Synaptic Package Manager).

I am not a programmer and am relatively new to linux.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: followed this: https://gist.github.com/raelgc/4ccc023830bfd12c0227 and was able to successfully install Office 2010.  Had to add samba and winbind with: sudo apt-get install playonlinux samba winbind - also recommended  install Wine 2.13.     Anyway - it worked